# What is the purpose of the "!" in this TypeScript method call?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was reading through some Angular documentation and the following code has stumped me.  Specifically, there is a a call to a method named `resolve`, but sandwiched between the parenthesis and the method name is a "!".

```
clicked() {
    if (this.arrived) {
      this.reset();
    } else {
      this.resolve!('hi there!'); \\<-- Here?
      this.arrived = true;
    }
}
```

I've never seen this before.  Why is there a bang after the method name?  I've tried to search for this and I can't find an answer.  Also, I'm not sure if this is a TypeScript or JavaScript thing.

For reference, the Angular reference document is the page on [the AsyncPipe object](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).  The code is in the second to last code snippet, close to the bottom of the snippet.  What is this code doing?

Comment: Yeah, this is a duplicate.  The example the code above comes from has the `resolve` property defined as type `Function | null`. Presumably if `this.arrived` is `true`, then `this.resolve` will be defined.  The compiler won't know about this dependency, so it would still complain that `this.resolve('hi there')` might be an error because `this.resolve` might be `null`.  The non-null assertion in `this.resolve!` says to the compiler that `this.resolve` should be treated as `Function` and not `Function | null` in that expression.

Comment: It is called "definite assignment assertion" and [has been introduced in TypeScript 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) (January 2018).